# R: Adjacency list to Adjacency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

Bonjour, I would like to convert an adjacency list (3 columns ) to an adjacency matrix. In this forum I have found multiple examples on how to convert an edge list to an adjacency matrix. I successfully managed to do it for a two columns list.
I have tried all the solutions I could find on the web but it seems that I missing a little step.

## What I tried

My variables are User, Country, books

```
User<-c("maman","sophia","Antoine")  
Country<-c("Canada","USA","Mexico")  
books<-c("Coelho","Rimbaud","The flight") 
dat<-data.frame(User, Country,books)  


User |       Country | books   
maman |        Canada  |    Coelho   
sophia|          USA  |    Rimbaud  
Antoine|     Mexico  | The flight
```

### First attempt

```
library(igraph)     
m<-as.matrix(dat)    
g<-graph.adjacency(m, mode="directed") ### If that worked I could have used      
"get.adjacency"
```

### Second attempt

Tried to convert the data to an edge list but I got an error since there is three columns

```
el<-as.matrix(dat)       
g=graph.edgelist(el,directed=TRUE) # turns
```

## Excepted output

```
     maman sophia Antoine Canada USA Mexico Coelho Rimbaud The fligth
maman    1   0     1       0      0   0      0        1          0
sophia   0   0     0       0      1   0      1        0          1
Antoine  0   1     1       0      1   0      0        1          0
Canada   1   0     1       0      0   1      0        1          1
 USA     0   0     0       1      0   0      0        0          1
 Mexico  0   0     0       0      1   1      1        0          0 
Coelho   0   0     1       1      0    1      0       1          0
Rimbaud  1   0     1       1      0    0      0       1          1
The fligth 0 1     0       0      1    1      0       0          1
```

I would like to see the interactions between all the vertices. Something similar to this: http://sna.stanford.edu/sna_R_labs/output/lab_1/1.3_Krackhardt_Friendship.pdf

Any help or indication would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you're after:

```
m <- as.matrix(dat)
el <- cbind(m[, 1], c(m[, -1]))
```

Here, `el` is an edge list, created by binding the first column of `m`, with a vector that is made by removing the dimensions of the matrix subset `m[, 2:3]` (equivalent to `m[, -1]`). Note that the first vector in the `cbind` has 3 elements, while the second vector has 6 elements. The first will be recycled to the length of the second. What we've done is equivalent to doing `cbind(rep(m[, 1], 2), m[, -1])`.

Here's what our edge list looks like.

```
el
##      [,1]      [,2]        
## [1,] "maman"   "Canada"    
## [2,] "sophia"  "USA"       
## [3,] "Antoine" "Mexico"    
## [4,] "maman"   "Coelho"    
## [5,] "sophia"  "Rimbaud"   
## [6,] "Antoine" "The flight"
```

We can now get the adjacency matrix by graphing the edge list with `graph.edgelist` and extracting the adjacency matrix with `get.adjacency`.

```
get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(el))

## 9 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##            maman Canada sophia USA Antoine Mexico Coelho Rimbaud The flight
## maman          .      1      .   .       .      .      1       .          .
## Canada         .      .      .   .       .      .      .       .          .
## sophia         .      .      .   1       .      .      .       1          .
## USA            .      .      .   .       .      .      .       .          .
## Antoine        .      .      .   .       .      1      .       .          1
## Mexico         .      .      .   .       .      .      .       .          .
## Coelho         .      .      .   .       .      .      .       .          .
## Rimbaud        .      .      .   .       .      .      .       .          .
## The flight     .      .      .   .       .      .      .       .          .
```

Comment: Perfect!!!  it is working :) I would like also to understand your code. Could you explain from graph.edgelist(........) ?

Comment: I just tried  when the number of rows are superior to three, and it doesn't produce a matrix. Is there a way to create an adjacency matrix?

Comment: @Shean10000 - The following example of a 5x3 matrix works for me: `m <- replicate(3, sample(letters, 5)); get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(cbind(m[, 1], c(m[, -1]))))`.

Comment: @Shean10000 - I've made things a little clearer now.

Comment: I have tried this for the matrix m :  m <- replicate(3, sample(dat, 6)); I have added 3 others lines.  str(dat) gives 3 variables and 6 obs. I got this error: "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE"

Comment: @Shean10000 - That's an unrelated error telling you that you're trying to sample more columns than the data frame has. If you can construct a data frame for which my solution doesn't work, post it here and I'll take a look. (BTW, you can enclose text in backticks, (`shift`+`~`) to format it as code in comments... see [this lnk](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more info.)

Comment: @Shean10000 - `replicate` is irrelevant to the problem - I just used it to concisely create some random data. I could have also used `data.frame(sample(letters, 5), sample(letters, 5), sample(letters, 5))`.