# r create adjacency matrix or edge list from adjacency list

Tags: r, networking, igraph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency list and I am trying to make it into and adjacency matrix or edge list. This is in order to conduct network analysis on the network built from the adjacency matrix or edge list. I am using R.
An example of adjacency list is as follows (each row has different amount of entries, and the empty entries are NA):

```
[17,50,90,NA,NA;
80,67,NA,NA,NA;
33,31,32, NA,NA;
33,31,32,NA,NA;
354,56,87,97,32;
....]
```

I tried using [R: Adjacency list to Adjacency matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290830/r-adjacency-list-to-adjacency-matrix) but this only works if my adjacency list has two entries (ie there are more than two neighbors in a group). I get an edge list but only taking into account the first two entries in my list.

I also tried using [From list to adjacency matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378237/from-list-to-adjacency-matrix) but using `igraph` and `make_graph(unlist(mydata))` led to the error: `"At type_indexededgelist.c:117 : cannot create empty graph with negative number of vertices, Invalid value"`

I need an adjacency matrix which takes into account the weights that would be in the network (like if entry 31 and 32 are in two rows, then their edge weight would be 2). 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an adjacency list and I am trying to make it into an[...] edge list.

Maybe you could do

```
lst <- read.csv(header=F, comment.char=";", colClasses="integer", text="
17,50,90,NA,NA;
80,67,NA,NA,NA;
33,31,32,NA,NA;
33,31,32,NA,NA;
354,56,87,97,32;")
m <- as.matrix(lst)
e <- stack(split(m, row(m)))[,2:1]
(e <- e[complete.cases(e),])
# 1    1     17
# 2    1     50
# 3    1     90
# 6    2     80
# 7    2     67
# 11   3     33
# 12   3     31
# 13   3     32
# 16   4     33
# 17   4     31
# 18   4     32
# 21   5    354
# 22   5     56
# 23   5     87
# 24   5     97
# 25   5     32
```

or

```
e <- apply(lst, 1, function(x)x[!is.na(x)])
(e <- do.call(rbind, lapply(e, embed, 2))[,2:1])
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   17   50
# [2,]   50   90
# [3,]   80   67
# [4,]   33   31
# [5,]   31   32
# [6,]   33   31
# [7,]   31   32
# [8,]  354   56
# [9,]   56   87
# [10,]   87   97
# [11,]   97   32
```

depending on what you need/what your "adjacency list" represents.

Comment: Thank you very much. For the second answer using apply, is there any way to also have a row listing the 1st and 3rd entries as neighbors? For instance, the third row would be values [17,90]. This would continue for additional entries, such as listing the 1st and 8th entry in my data.

Comment: @CatalinaGutierrez You might want to check out `?expand.grid()` and/or `?combn()`.

Comment: Ignore that last comment. Update:  I tried using comb by `co = combn(e[[1]],2)` where e is from using apply. I converted to a data.frame and used transpose to get the edge list: [17,50; 17,90; 50,90] . I was able to do this for all the values and got a complete edge list. But, when turning this into a graph and adjacency matrix, I believe it recounts any repeated pairs. I need to turn this into a weighted adjacency matrix and graph. For ex, if [17,50] shows up twice in my edge list, this means the weight of the edge between 17 and 50 is two. Any ideas?  Thank you again!

Comment: @CatalinaGutierrez Check out `igraph::simplify()` to aggregate multiple edges.